# Tensorflow 2.0 Input being creating with first shape element as None

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to create an Input in the following way:

```py
    Tx = 318
    n_freq = 101
    input_anchor = Input(shape=(n_freq,Tx), name='input_anchor')
```

When I run:

```py
    input_anchor.shape
```

I get:

```py
    TensorShape([None, 101, 318])
```

Later when I try to use that input in my model I get the following error:

```py
    TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
```

In [Tensor flow's opy.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py) I found this code block which is most likely where my code is failing:

```py
     def __iter__(self):
        if not context.executing_eagerly():
          raise TypeError(
              "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "
              "enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.")
        shape = self._shape_tuple()
        if shape is None:
          raise TypeError("Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown shape.")
        if not shape:
          raise TypeError("Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.")
        if shape[0] is None:
          raise TypeError(
              "Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.")
        for i in xrange(shape[0]):
          yield self[i]
```

If you want to see my whole model implementation here it is:

```py
    def base_model(input_shape):

        X_input = Input(shape = input_shape)


        # Step 1: CONV layer (≈4 lines)
        X = Conv1D(196,kernel_size = 15, strides = 4)(X_input)                                 # CONV1D
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization
        X = Activation('relu')(X)                                 # ReLu activation
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)

        # Step 2: First GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
        X = LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X_input)                                 # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization

        # Step 3: Second GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
        X = LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X)                                 # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)

        # Step 4: Third GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
        X = LSTM(units = 128)(X)                                 # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization
        X = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)

        X = Dense(64)(X)

        base_model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X)

        return base_model  

    def speech_model(input_shape, base_model):

        #get triplets vectors
        input_anchor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_anchor')
        input_positive = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_positive')
        input_negative = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_negative')

        vec_anchor = base_model(input_anchor)
        vec_positive = base_model(input_positive)
        vec_negative = base_model(input_negative)

        #Concatenate vectors vec_positive, vec_negative
        concat_layer = concatenate([vec_anchor,vec_positive,vec_negative], axis = -1, name='concat_layer')

        model = Model(inputs = [input_anchor,input_positive,input_negative], outputs = concat_layer, name = 'speech_to_vec')
        #model = Model(inputs = [input_anchor,input_positive,input_negative], outputs = [vec_anchor,vec_positive,vec_negative], name = 'speech_to_vec')
        #model = Model(inputs = [input_anchor,input_positiv], outputs=vec_anchor)


        return model
```

And the line that breaks it all and generates the error mentioned before

```py
    speech_model = speech_model(input_shape = (n_freq, Tx), base_model = base_model)
```

Thanks a lot for reading, any kind of help towards solving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `base_model(input_shape)` function requires you to pass in `tuple`, but you pass `Input Layer` to it.

```
# change
vec_anchor = base_model(input_anchor)
vec_positive = base_model(input_positive)
vec_negative = base_model(input_negative)
# to
vec_anchor = base_model(input_shape)
vec_positive = base_model(input_shape)
vec_negative = base_model(input_shape)
```

In addition, you need to correct the input and output of the final model since `concatenate` can't concat multiple model type.

```
concat_layer = concatenate([vec_anchor.output,vec_positive.output,vec_negative.output], axis = -1, name='concat_layer')

model = Model(inputs = [vec_anchor.input,vec_positive.input,vec_negative.input], outputs = concat_layer, name = 'speech_to_vec')
```